# Single lens for both portrait and landscape

Tags: lens, nikon, dslr

Is there any budget lens for Nikon d5600 which is best for both portrait and landscape? I'm looking for one lens which does both portrait and landscape.

Comment: Did you get a kit lens with your camera? If so, what's wrong with that one? If not, what lens(es) do you have?

Comment: What is "best"? What _kind_ of portrait and landscape?

Comment: @osullic yes i do have 18-55 mm kit lens but i'm looking for creamy blur in portrait and sharpness in landscape which i'm not satisfied with the kit one. So i'm thinking of upgrading the lens.

Comment: @mattdm In terms of best, i want creamy blur in portrait and sharp photo in landscape. I do have the kit 18-55mm but i want to upgrade with the best budget lens which can do both.

Comment: That raises another question: what is "budget"?

Comment: I'm not a professional photographer, i'm a student. So i'm looking for cheap but best in performance lens.

Comment: @AkashShrestha the blur that you are looking for can be achieved with your 18-55. You need to work on the `Aperture` or `f-number` depending on the distances between the camera & object and object & background.

Comment: @NewBee yes but the sharpness and bokeh as 50mm f/1.8g, we can't get from 18-55mm right?

Comment: @AkashShrestha In portraits, sharpness is not necessarily desirable and some dedicated portrait lenses are marketed as "soft focus."

Answer (score 3):

The most important part of taking good portraits is not the lens. It is capturing interesting subjects in good light. The percentage of good portraits will go up more quickly by improving lighting technique (and perhaps equipment) than by improving lenses. These days, many good portraits often entail post processing. Software and hardware and knowledge relevant for post processing may also significantly improve the quality of portraits. Having an appropriate wardrobe and finding good locations will also have a bigger impact on portrait photographs than the lens. So will a tripod (and perhaps a used Mamiya RB67 set upon it).

Similarly with landscapes. Interesting subjects in interesting light will have more impact than a particular lens. Techniques involving long exposures and post-processing multiple exposures and neutral density filters will also have more impact on the quality of a landscape image than a particular lens. And if the goal is pursuit of Ansel Adams level, it's film and a view camera with movements.

In the end, effort and applied knowledge have more influence on photographic results than the quality of equipment. Shopping for better equipment is easier than learning to take better photographs. Learning to take better photographs means understanding the compromises that are inherent in every piece of photographic equipment.

Comment: Yes i understand, and thank you so much for your advice. But if you have to suggest one good lens which one it will be?

Comment: @AkashShrestha The best lens is the one on the end of your camera (when your camera is out of the bag). Go out and take pictures. Learn how to get people to sit for portraits. Learn how to light them. Travel to interesting landscapes and wait for good light.

Comment: Yes i'm practicing and learning day by day. Mean while i've only 18-55mm kit lens

Comment: @AkashShrestha I think your question would be better if it included some samples of your work and a description of why the results are unsatisfactory...it should perhaps be another question because nobody can say what lens you should buy and the dissatisfying elements of your images can almost certainly be mitigated with technique and planning. Everything is a tradeoff. Getting a good portrait with a 50mm @ f1.8 requires careful control of focus plane and posing. The bokeh may be great by the subject is often not.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the comments, I feel you "do not get the picture".

> budget lens for Nikon d5600 which is best for both portrait and landscape

**The best lens that covers that is... the Kit lens**. That is why they provide it. Budget+Best+Portrait+Landscape. I must say, these lenses are quite good, not only for the price but for the overall result.

If you really learn how to use it you will get good images.

If you are not satisfied with the results there is a chance a lot of things are somehow wrong. Light, exposure, composition.

---

Beyond that you need either an EXPENSIVE lens that can do both (basically a wider aperture+sharper zoom lens)

or **one economic 50mm f/1.8 lens to do portraits** and use the kit lens for the landscapes.

If you are a student, and you are learning photography, i sugest you learn about this, and do not expect any magical solutions. n_n

---

One option is that you find an used lens with an aperture of at least 2.8. Take a look at this table: https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/camera-lenses/all-lenses/index.page

And filter the options.

Answer (score 0):

Nikon camera comes with 18-55 lens which you can use for both.

IIRC there is a 16-55 lens. You can use that too.

Comment: There is also an 18-300.

Comment: @benrudgers yes. Is it of the same cost as that of 16-55? I'm not too sure of the price.